# How to prevent user to access the SharePoint Apps on the site collection if user dont have access to Site Collection?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, user, app-permissions

I have a SharePoint Online user **USER-1** and Site Collection as **Site-1**.

**Scenario:**

Now, **USER-1** does not have permission to access the **Site-1**, but an app installed in **Site-1** is accessible to the **USER-1** if direct url to the app is provided to the **USER-1**.

I want to prevent this accessibility.

Any suggestion is most welcome.

**Edit:** Its a SharePoint Hosted App.

The permission of the app is as follow.

[image: Permission of App]

Comment: provider hosted or sharepoint hosted app ?